# Loading JSON data as external script instead of AJAX

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

I have been shown a trick - instead of having the data in datafile.json and load it with ajax, the data is encapsulated in a single object in a datafile.js such as var Data = { //all data goes here }. Then the datafile.js is just loaded as external script in the html head

It works well just as if the objects were loaded with ajax, are there any drawbacks to this?

Comment: Be it a on a .json file or .js file, basically it is a javascript object notation. Hence the behavior and performance would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

JSON *is* JavaScript. *(Back in the day, the idea was that you could simply `eval` it ...)*  Therefore, the file that you speak of is simply ... "a JavaScript assignment-statement, stored in a file."

The only potential issue with storing this as a separate file might be "a timing hole."  The source-code must be separately retrieved. I'm not sure if the browser would *wait* to do that, so it might be possible for other JavaScript code to execute that does not see `var Data` because that block of code hasn't been retrieved and executed *yet.*

When you have "lots of invariant fixed data," I customarily put everything including the data into *one* ("yeah, it's big ...") JS file, so that I know "it's all there" before any of it tries to be executed. Yes, there are definite advantages to simply including *fixed* data directly into your source-file, as you're effectively doing here, but I'm not sure I see an advantage (and, I might see a hole ...) in using *several* JS files.

Comment: Thank you very much! My feedback doesn't count yet, but I upheld your answer