# Load data from local JSON file into javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

[added:] Thank you guys for the reply.  I understand that ajax has to used on a server.  I wonder if there is a way to load the data from **local json file** into js in this example?

---

I have a file named `employee.json`. I tried load this JSON data into JavaScript.  I saved both the .json and .html files on my desktop but when I click in the HTML, there is nothing shown. I tried to use `alert()` in the `.ajax()` method but it does not work. I am not sure what is wrong with my AJAX method. What do I need to do to take the `id` from the JSON and put it into an array in javaScript? Thank you in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
    <p id="demo"></p>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script>
          var res = [];

          $.ajax({
              url: 'employee.json',
              dataType: 'json',
              method: 'get',
              cache: false,              
              success: function(data) {
                  $(data.employee).each(function(index, value) {                
                     res.push(value.id);
                  });
                  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.toString();                     
              }
          });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
{
    "employee": [{
        "id" : 1,
        "firstName" : "Lokesh"
    },{
        "id" : 2,
        "firstName" : "bryant"
    },{
        "id" : 3,
        "firstName" : "kobe"
    }]
}
```

Comment: `I saved both .json and .html file on my desktop` You cannot run AJAX requests on the local file system due to the security restrictions on modern browsers. If you check the console you'll probably see a lot of errors and warnings about this. You need to run on a web server.

Comment: Oh nice to know this.  What if I want to load json from local file into js.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: as @RoryMcCrossan said you can't run AJAX call on local file server.. use any web server. If you are using Chrome use extension web server for chrome, i found it pretty useful https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/web-server-for-chrome/ofhbbkphhbklhfoeikjpcbhemlocgigb?hl=en

Comment: Yes - as I mentioned you need to run your code on a web server. You can run a web server on your local machine quite easily. Google IIS or XAMP, amongst others. Note that you should use `console.log()` to debug, not `alert()`. Also, you can replace `document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res.toString();` with `$('#demo').html(res)`

Comment: Check your console and give us the error.
You're getting no alert because ajax doesn't enter in success.

you could add a `error: function(){alert('error')})` and you'll see the alert

Comment: when you say console, do you mean the tool in chrome? When I press F12, it gives a console. Is this the console you are talking about?

Comment: Tested it and it works, just make sure you are running this on a server.

Comment: Thank you guys.  I wonder is there a way to load json from a local file?

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can load your JSON as a javascript, just wrap all your JSON data into

```
    var employees = { /*all your json data here*/ }
```

and save this as employees.js

Then you can just use a regular script tag in the html:

```
<script src="/yourpath/employees.js"/>
```

And then inside your javascript "employees" will be a global object.
so you will have:

```
  employess.employee[1].FirstName
```

result in "bryant" in your case;

Comment: Thank you for the response Dimitar.  I like this idea however I may not use this way to solve my problem since at first I convert java object into local json file and now I have the problem load the local json data into js.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38525494/loading-json-data-as-external-script-instead-of-ajax